# QGIS crash when programatically removing layer

Tags: pyqgis, remove

I have to remove a layer named "Punti_da_csv_utente" and I use the following code:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    #(other code)

    for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name() == "Punti_da_csv_utente":
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([lyr.id()])
```

but sometimes, not always, qgis crashes.

Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Maybe due to multithreading as the layer is in the main thread and has GUI objects (like a name in the layer tree, etc.), and the processing alg try to remove it from another thread, and in this case Qt (so QGIS) crashes.

Comment: thank you very much for your kind reply. In your opinion, what could be a way to eliminate this problem?

Comment: IMHO, create a function / method to remove maplayers and emit a signal in your processing alg, connected to the function / method. So, the signal is independent of the GUI thread, can move between main and other threads and once recieved by the main thread, the layer can be removed without crashing QGIS (if it was the problem ...).

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice!